# How to change width of dropdownlist only of a spinner programmatically - android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

in my app I am using a Spinner to show a list of items.
I am changing the width of the spinner in my code dynamically, but the width of the dropdown is also changing along with the spinner.

I want to fix the width of the dropdown list but not for spinner.
So how can I do this without using xml?

Answer (score 2):

Set dropdown width in xml file of spinner using the tag

```
android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/desired_width"
```

Explaination :

```
    mDropDownWidth = pa.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.Spinner_dropDownWidth,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

this field is used for dropdown width when spinner item is initialized in Spinner class

for programatically changing spinner dropdown width above api level 16, use

```
mSpinner.setDropDownWidth(size_in_pixel);
```